# Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8

Tags: javascript, database, html, indexeddb

I am having a strange issue with using indexeddb API in Javascript. The code below generate the error in the subject line:

```
 var notesdisplay, db;
function initiate(){
  notesdisplay = document.getElementById('notesdisplay');
  var button = document.getElementById('save');
  button.addEventListener('click', addobject);

  var request = indexedDB.open('mydatabase');
  request.addEventListener('error', showerror);
  request.addEventListener('success', start);
  request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', createdb);
}
function showerror(e){
  alert('Error: ' + e.code + ' ' + e.message);
}
function start(e){
  db = e.target.result;
  show();
}
function createdb(e){
  var datababase = e.target.result;
  var mystore = datababase.createObjectStore('notesTable', {keyPath: 'id'});
  mystore.createIndex('searchNotes', 'id', {unique: false});
}
function addobject(){
  var title = document.getElementById('notesbox').value;

  var mytransaction = db.transaction(['notesTable'], "readwrite");
  var mystore = mytransaction.objectStore('notesTable');
  var request = mystore.add({id: title});
  request.addEventListener('success', show);

  document.getElementById('notesbox').value = '';
}

function show(){
  notesdisplay.innerHTML = '';
  var mytransaction = db.transaction(['notesTable']);
  var mystore = mytransaction.objectStore('notesTable');
  var myindex = mystore.index('searchNotes');
  var newcursor = myindex.openCursor(null, "prev");
  newcursor.addEventListener('success', showlist);
}
function showlist(e){
  var cursor = e.target.result;
  if(cursor){
    notesdisplay.innerHTML += '<div>' + cursor.value.id + ' - ' + ' <input type="button" onclick="removeobject(\'' + cursor.value.id + '\')" value="remove"></div>';

    cursor.continue();
  }
}
function removeobject(keyword){
  if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
    var mytransaction = db.transaction(['notesTable'], "readwrite");
    var mystore = mytransaction.objectStore('notesTable');
    var request = mystore.delete(keyword);
    request.addEventListener('success', show);
  }
}
addEventListener('load', initiate);
```

When I run this from within Chrome I get the error in the subject line. However, when I run this from Firefox a different error is generated (probably on the same lines).

--

> [19:13:54.870] TypeError: db is undefined

Although I am fairly new to Javascript, in my mind the variable db is defined within the start function as here:

> function start(e){   db = e.target.result;   show(); }

This program is a simplified version of an example I had obtained from a book. This only has one key / value pair.

Any suggestions / pointers as to what could be the issue would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

vnayak

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce your error, see http://jsbin.com/ulemat/2/edit in Chrome `Version 26.0.1410.64 m`, chances are you're using an out-dated Chrome version (Chrome had a lot of issues in the past with the implementation)

Comment: The version of Chrome I am using is `Version 26.0.1410.65` and Firefox is `20.0`. It asked me for the update a few day back nad after that the original tutorial code I had started working fine. So it may well be a version thing...

Answer (score 0):

Your request to open a database connection could be getting blocked. Try adding the following to your initiate function

```
request.addEventListener('blocked', function() { console.log('blocked'); });
```